# Machine learning and actual predictions

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I have a question about machine learning regarding predictions.

So typically I would have a dataset with x's and y's that i would train my algo on. But what if I just have a dataset with input variables only (x's) and no actual predictions (y's)?

For example, im looking for fradulent transactions.

In dataset A i have a bunch of input variables like amounts, zipcodes, merchant, etc. and i have a fraud status variable that says 1 for possible fraud, 0 for safe transaction. Here i have known frauds/known non frauds that i can train my model on.

However, what if i have a dataset where there is no fraud varaible. All i have is my input variables and no variable that indicates whether it is fraud or not. How could an ML algo then predict the probability of it being a fraudulent transaction for this specific dataset?

Comment: You are asking about unsupervised learning, a very broad topic, and not really on-topic at StackOverflow anyway. There are data-science/machine-learning specific stack exchange sites that would be better suited.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is anomaly detection. In anomaly detection, you will try to find the datapoints, which are different from the rest of the data points, in your case it is fraudulent transaction.

There are quite a few algorithms available in sklearn, look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html). I would recommend start with IsolationForest model for your problem.

From Documentation.

[image]